# .NET Core mvc UseSpa UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer serves build version instead of development version

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, lit-element

I'm using LitElements to build my frontend. I want to configure .net core mvc spa with it.

here how my config looks like:
Startup.cs

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "wwwsrc";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:8000");
    }
});
```

When I run `http://localhost:8000` it serves proper dev version. 
But when I run .net core app on `http://localhost:50001/` it shows build production version and I have to run `npm run build` in order to see my changes. 
How do I configure .net core app in order to see dev version?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Project Launch Settings or Environment variable to control the Environment.

Refer [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more details.